# How to filter data where a field contains a something with OData

Tags: rest, odata

I'm trying to filter all the data using OData where the FileRef constains let's say `'/sites/my_site/myfolder'`for this I tried something like: `$filter=substringof('/sites/my_site/myfolder', FileRef)` but it seems like it doesn´t work, so I wonder if is there a way in which I can get only the records that in its FileRef property contanins some.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to be an issue with SharePoint.

[UserVoice - Fix REST FileRef queries](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/15905419-fix-rest-fileref-queries)

However, you can use the `getitems` POST method along with CAML query to retrieve the items as below:

```
var queryText = '<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="FileRef"/><Value Type="Url">/sites/my_site/myfolder</Value></Contains></Where>';

var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
var webserviceUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/getitems"; //replace with your list/doc lib
var queryPayload = {  
           'query' : {
                  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                  'ViewXml' : viewXml,
           }
};

$.ajax({
           url: webserviceUrl,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           },
           success:function(data){
                var results = data.d.results;
                //iterate it over the results
                 for(var i = 0; i < results.length;i++) {
                     console.log(results[i].Title);
                 } 
           },
           error:function(data){
                console.log("something went wrong");
           }
});
```

[Using CAML with REST api](https://chuvash.eu/2014/03/25/using-caml-with-sharepoint-rest-api/)